# CoffeeScript loose compilation

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, coffeescript

Is there a way to compile CoffeeScript source loosely ignoring minor syntax errors like: `variable =` or `object.`? Is it possible out-of-the-box with stock compiler or some other compiler implementation?

If not, please point me to the right location of the CoffeeScript compiler where to implement this feature. After quick look at the source I think that it may be Rewriter class where I need to remove tokens which produce errors.

I need this in order to implement autocomplete in Ace editor using Tern by Marijn Haverbeke https://github.com/marijnh/tern

Comment: Maybe simply add a dummy token `__dummy` right after the current cursor position if the current source code fails to compile? That would work for both cases you mention. That is, I suppose people will mainly want autocomplete at the place their cursor is, not somewhere else.

Comment: The rewriter adds token, but does not know if it's producing invalid tokens or nut

Comment: I know, I have finite number of such cases which rewriter can handle. Actually, I've succeeded with doing it in rewriter yesterday, but Meryn's suggestion is also very interesting. Anyway, I'll have to do source mapping from CS to JS first. I'll share my findings then.